# CSS for fullscreen API don't work for me

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullscreen

I have a page which contains a `div` that I would like to make full-screen when the user clicks a link.

I have tried doing this with CSS but it does not work

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DIV with full screen height</title>
        <style>
            #map-canvas {
                height: 590px;
                width:1100px;
                border: 2px solid #326195;
                margin: 5px;
            }
            html:-moz-full-screen #map-canvas {
                height: 100%;
                width:100%;
            }
            html:-webkit-full-screen #map-canvas {
                height: 100%;
                width:100%;
            }
            html:-ms-fullscreen #map-canvas {
                height: 100%;
                width:100%;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            var element, fullscreenbtn;

            function intializePlayer() {
                element = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
                fullscreenbtn = document.getElementById('fullscreenbtn');
                // Add event listeners
                fullscreenbtn.addEventListener('click', toggleFullScreen, false);
            }
            window.onload = intializePlayer;

            var fullScreen = false;

            function toggleFullScreen() {
                debugger;
                if (!element.fullscreenElement && // alternative standard method
                !element.mozFullScreenElement && !element.webkitFullscreenElement) { // current working methods
                    if (element.requestFullscreen) {
                        element.requestFullscreen();

                    } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                        element.mozRequestFullScreen();

                    } else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
                        element.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (element.cancelFullScreen) {
                        element.cancelFullScreen();
                    } else if (element.mozCancelFullScreen) {
                        delementocument.mozCancelFullScreen();
                    } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
                        element.webkitCancelFullScreen();
                    }
                }
            }            
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" id="fullscreenbtn" style="z-index: 10;">plein ecran</a>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Does it do the wrong thing, or does nothing happen, or is there some sort of error?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `html` in front of `full-screen` selectors and remove `space` between `full-screen` selectors and div selector:

```
:-moz-full-screen#map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

:-webkit-full-screen#map-canvas {
   height: 100%;
   width:100%;
}

:-ms-fullscreen#map-canvas {
   height: 100%;
   width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give to `<body>`and `<HTML>` `height: 100%`

**CSS**

```
body,html{
height: 100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

> Note: You always should give height:100%; to his parent to have full height

Answer (score -1):

Try to do it:

```
#map_canvas{
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
}
```

You also have to check if the page is allowed to understand HTML5, before  tag you have to have:

```
<!doctype html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    #map-canvas:-webkit-full-screen  { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
    #map-canvas:-moz-full-screen     { width: 100% ; height: 100%;}
    #map-canvas:-ms-full-screen      { width: 100% ; height: 100%;}
    #map-canvas:-o-full-screen       { width: 100% ; height: 100%;}
```

Comment: While this post may answer the question, it is still a good idea to add some explanation and, possibly, some links to the relevant documentation. Answers with good explanations and references are usually more useful both to the current OP and to the future visitors. Full detailed answers are also more likely to attract positive votes.